# Custom Number Picker with no plus & minus Sign

Tags: android

I'm very new to android . I am now trying to develop custom number picker without plus and minus sign . Can someone help me doing this ? Is is possible . Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two solutions:

1. You can use wheelpicker (same as iPhone) instead of number picker.
2. you can change theme in holo from your manifest file. So number picker will show as scroller.

Comment: How can I use wheel picker . Please with some example . Apologize

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/03/custom-picker-in-android-number-picker.html

this code is perfectly working...please check this one.

Comment: But it'll cover up the screen it call you . Not ok with me . I'm now tryin' to use wheel picker but some exception occur :(

Comment: please post your error here

Comment: Already fix that thanks for concern > i'll mark yours as right answer :)